# How many days are there in each year of the 304th Metonic cycle?

Tags: calendar, time

I need the number of days per year for my continuous Hebrew calender.

Comment: Just confirming that you want this information for the previous (304th) cycle, not the current (305th) cycle?

Comment: Yes - correct - I need the detail for a completed cycle.

Comment: OK. Just be aware that one nineteen year cycle is not (necessarily) the same as the next in terms of number of days per year

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar

Comment: That I understand. I need to see each year's starting Gregorian date, Hebrew date, the days per year and to confirm that the total years add up to 6940 days.

Comment: I need to add the cycle to itself to build my continious calender. A website - britannica.com/science/Metonic-cycle indicates the following: Metonic cycle computed: 235 Lunations = 6939 days, 16.5 hrs    19 solar years =   6939 days, 14.5 hrs. My spreadsheet agrees exactly with your spreadsheet. Both add up to 6941 days. I am not sure which number of days to use to build my continious calender

Comment: As noted in the wikipedia article quoted by Danny Schoemann "due to the Rosh Hashanah postponement rules...a cycle of 19 Jewish years can be either 6,939, 6,940, 6,941, or 6,942 days in duration"

Comment: "Since none of these values is evenly divisible by seven, the Jewish calendar repeats exactly only following 36,288 Metonic cycles, or 689,472 Jewish years. There is a near-repetition every 247 years"

Comment: So to add on cycles to build a continious calender will not work?

Comment: Not 19 year cycles, no. A 247-year cycle can get you part of the way there, but for complete accuracy you need a full 689,472-year cycle.

Comment: Is it then possible to determine a gregorian date for a hebrew festival day in say the year 3500?

Comment: https://www.hebcal.com/converter/  seems to work until the year 9999

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Here's a screenshot of part of an excel calendar that I made a while ago, which answers your question:

[image]

Comment: Is it OK with you to share your excel calendar

Comment: @eliavs https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90044/14850 and follow the link to google sheets